# How can I get all possible permutations of a 2 by 2 matrix using a vector of values such as 0:9?

Tags: r, matrix, permutation

I have ran into an issue in one of my assignments. I have been asked to find the determinant of all possible permutations of 2 by 2 matrices using values 0:9. However, I can't seem to find all possible matrices. I have tried using the combn function, but this will only give me matrices with unique elements (in other words, it does not return matrices with repeating elements such as 1,1,0,2). Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

I have tried something similar to this.

```
x <- 0:9
combn(x, 4)
```

The end result should be a vector of determinants of all possible 2 by 2 matrices using numbers 0:9.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach:

```
# the input vector
x <- c(0:9)

# all 2x2 matrices
pos <- expand.grid(x,x,x,x)

# all dets:
dets <- pos$Var1*pos$Var3 - pos$Var2 * pos$Var4

# unique dets
unique(dets)
```

Output:

```
  [1]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  12  14  16  18  15  21  24  27  20  28  32  36  25  30  35  40  45  42  48  54  49  56
 [34]  63  64  72  81  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9  11  13  17  23  26  19  22  31  34  29  33  39  44  38  43  37  41  47  53  46
 [67]  52  51  50  55  62  61  60  59  58  57  71  70  69  68  67  66  65  80  79  78  77  76  75  74  73 -10 -12 -14 -16 -18 -11 -13 -15
[100] -17 -21 -24 -27 -20 -19 -23 -22 -26 -25 -28 -32 -36 -31 -30 -29 -35 -34 -33 -40 -45 -39 -38 -37 -44 -43 -42 -41 -48 -54 -47 -46 -53
[133] -52 -51 -50 -49 -56 -63 -55 -62 -61 -60 -59 -58 -57 -64 -72 -71 -70 -69 -68 -67 -66 -65 -81 -80 -79 -78 -77 -76 -75 -74 -73
```

Answer (score 2):

`RcppAlgos` is a great package for this type of problem.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

x<- 0:9

unlist(
  permuteGeneral(x, 4, repetition = T, FUN = function(y) det(matrix(y,2)))
)
# or for better performance

mat <- permuteGeneral(x, 4, repetition = T)
mat[,1] * mat[, 3] - mat[, 2] * mat[, 4]
```

Or you can see your `2x2` matrix slices in an array:

```
array(t(permuteGeneral(x, 4, repetition = T)), c(2,2,2500))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
my_determinant_function <- function(x){
  det(matrix(x, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
}

df <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:9), 4))
apply(df,1, my_determinant_function)
```